# Onchange radio button after clone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html code with radio buttons and some common button. After click common button I copy this code with `.clone` and insert after with `.after`. In first block I have radio buttons with name like 'name', in second I change this name like '1name', in third -'2name' and etc. Moreover I have js code

```
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
            var index= $(this).attr('rbgindex');
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            $('.hid-'+name).remove();
            $(this).parent().after('<input class=hid-'+name+' type=hidden name='+name+index+' value='+index+' checked>');
    });
```

It should create hidden filed after change radio button. But I have problem with it. If I change radio button in firsy work, it work, but in another it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Add your html to question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(document).on('change')` event for change event handling

```
$(document).on('change','input[type=radio]',function(){
      var index= $(this).attr('rbgindex');
      var name = $(this).attr('name');
      $('.hid-'+name).remove();
      $(this).parent().after('<input class=hid-'+name+' type=hidden name='+name+index+' value='+index+' checked>');
});
```